# Centrar div con CSS

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Estoy realizando un perfil con su imagen de verificado, pero no logro conseguir que la imagen `check` se ponga al lado de la imagen del perfil, puse el div padre del check como `position:absolute` pero tampoco me funciona.

```css
.profile-banner{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background: blue;
}


.content-profile{
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.check-profile img{
    width: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-banner">
      <div class="content-profile">
        <div class="profile-img">
        <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="check-profile">
          <div class="check-profile-position">
            <img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name-ml">
          <span>User Name</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que la imagen de verificado esté como este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando tu marcado, primero debes hacer `.check-profile` un elemento `inline-block` o `inline` para que no ocupe el 100% del contenedor. Luego, hacerlo absoluto y al padre `.content-profile` hacerlo relativo para que el check lo tome como referencia al posicionar. Finalmente, para que esté en el borde derecho, haz uso de `calc` para sumar `50px` (mitad del ancho del avatar) a `50%` (centro).

**Ejemplo**

```css
.profile-banner {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background: blue;
}

.content-profile {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.check-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 50px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.check-profile img {
  width: 20px
}

.profile-name-ml span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-banner">
  <div class="content-profile">
    <div class="profile-img">
      <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="check-profile">
      <div class="check-profile-position">
        <img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-name-ml">
      <span>User Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Usando un marcado apropiado no es necesario usar `calc` ni hacer el check absoluto. Solo basta agrupar el avatar con el check y hacerlos elementos en línea para que estén alineados horizontalmente.

**Ejemplo**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.profile-banner {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f39c12;
}

.content-profile {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-position: bottom 10px, right 10px;
}

.check-profile {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-profile img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px
}

.profile-name-ml {
  padding: 10px 25px 0 0;
}

.profile-name-ml span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-banner">
  <div class="content-profile">
    <div class="profile-img">
      <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
      <div class="check-profile">
        <div class="check-profile-position">
          <img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-name-ml">
      <span>User Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

También hay una tercera alternativa, usando `:after` para poner la imagen como fondo. Para el centrado vertical, haces el elemento `after` absoluto, le das `top: 50%` y `transform: translateY(-50%)`. Con esto el check se centrará verticalmente.

**Ejemplo**

```css
.profile-banner {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background: blue;
}

.content-profile {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-img:after {
  background: url("http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.check-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 50px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.check-profile img {
  width: 20px
}

.profile-name-ml span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-banner">
  <div class="content-profile">
    <div class="profile-img">
      <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-name-ml">
      <span>User Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muy buena explicación Gustavo, muchas gracias!!

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer que el div check este dentro del div de la imagen de perfil, le das al div la propiedad position:relative; y al check position:absolute; entonces ya puedes acomodar la posicion con top, left, right o bottom

```css
.profile-banner{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background: blue;
}


.content-profile{
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    
}
.profile-img{
 position:relative;
}


.check-profile img{
    width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     right:1;

 }
```

```html
<div class="profile-banner">
      <div class="content-profile">
        <div class="profile-img">
        <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
                <div class="check-profile">
         <div class="check-profile-position">
              <img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="profile-name-ml">
          <span>User Name</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola, Jorge gracias por la respuesta, pero el bottom:0 hace que la imagen de check se vaya hasta abajo : http://prntscr.com/f1o9ni

Comment: si acomodaste el div check-profile dentro del div profile-img, y le diste la propiedad relative a .profile-img

Comment: Si, era eso jejeje gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería aplicar una posición `relative` al `check` para luego manipular su posición con `top` , `left` .

```css
.profile-banner{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background: blue;
}


.content-profile{
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.check-profile img{
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top:-25px;
    left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-banner">
      <div class="content-profile">
        <div class="profile-img">
        <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="check-profile">
          <div class="check-profile-position">
            <img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name-ml">
          <span>User Name</span>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

O aplicar una Transformación directamente :

```
.check-profile img{
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;    
  transform: rotate(500deg) translate(-3em) rotate(-500deg);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Dev. Joel, el pero el div está ocupando un espacio jeje, alguna manera de hacerlo desaparecer? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ESPERO TE SIRVA ES MUY SIMPLE PERO EFECTIVA!

```html
<div align="center" style="background: blue;padding:40px;">
<img  src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="imagen" style="border-radius:100%;">
</div>
```