# Como centrar un div con CSS

Tags: css, div, frontend

Estoy realizando un perfil con su imagen de verificado, pero no logro conseguir que la imagen check se ponga al lado de la imagen del perfil, puse el div padre del check como position:absolute pero tampoco me funciona como podria hacerlo?

```
.profile-banner{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  min-height: 170px;
  background: blue;
}


.content-profile{
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}

.check-profile img{
    width: 20px
}
```

````
<div class="profile-banner">
      <div class="content-profile">
        <div class="profile-img">
        <img src="https://www.digmefitness.com/files/members/000/005/687/1490956902_1ZR6E_Blank-Avatar-Image.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="check-profile">
          <div class="check-profile-position">
            <img src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/1336ad9d5388454f9b451914f4129c22.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name-ml">
          <span>User Name</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Centrar div con CSS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66073/centrar-div-con-css)